# Passing a struct with array of structures from c# to c++

Tags: c#, c++

I have a c# hierarchy of structs.

```
private struct Vector3
{
    public float x;
    public float y;
    public float z;
}

private structure Location
{
    public Vector3 coords;
    public float distanceFromOrigin;
}

private struct Locations
{
    public Location[] locations;
}

private struct Scene
{
    public Locations cam1;
    public Locations cam2;
    public float timeInMilliSecs;
}
```

I'm instantiating the `Scene` and with `cam1` and `cam2` each gets an array of *10* Locations. Everything traces fine. Works as expected to this point and the data structure is populated with the correct data.

I'm passing the instance of `Scene` to an unmanaged DLL

```
[DllImport(dllname)]
private static extern void updateScene(Scene scene);
```

In my c++ I have

```
extern "C" {
    DLL_EXPORT void updateScene(Scene scene);
}
```

and an overload

```
void updateScene(Scene scene) {
    setSecene(scene); // this calls function fine but with erroneous data
}
```

and signatures for the equivalent structs

```
struct Vector3
{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
}

struct Location
{
    Vector3 coords;
    float distanceFromOrigin;
}

struct Locations
{
    Location locations[10];
}

struct Scene
{
    Locations cam1;
    Locations cam2;
    float timeInMilliSecs;
}
```

The `Scene` struct is passed into the `C` with the correct data structure but not the correct data, none of the Vector3s are right and `timeInMilliSecs` is always 0.

Previously I had `Locations` as individual instances of `Location` and that worked fine but since making it an array it doesn't work.

I'm guessing that I need to Marshall this across but I don't know where to start. Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 10)]
public Location[] locations;
```

Array in c# is a reference type.

Comment: thanks, @shingo - that passes the correct data now, however, when the updateScene() function completes in the DLL, it causes an access violation... any thoughts

Comment: Have you tried to set the CallingConvention to other value in dllimport attribute?

Comment: Or if the c code contains some memory access problem, this exception also throws.

Comment: I have not set a CallingConvention `[DllImport(dllname)]` - the C code is simply passing the value onto the  C++

Comment: Accepted answer because it did solve my problem with the data although it lead me to the next problem of the exception